# conda environment doesn't activate in bash script job on computing cluster

Tags: bash, conda, slurm

I am trying to submit a SLURM job on a computing cluster CentOS7.  The job is a python file (cifar100-vgg16.py) which needs tensorflow-gpu 2.8.1, which I've installed in a conda environment (tf_gpu).  The bash script I'm submitting to SLURM (our job scheduler) is copied below.  The SLURM output file shows that the environment being used is the base conda environment Python/3.6.4-foss-2018a (with tensorflow 1.10.1), not tf_gpu.  Please advise on how to solve.

Bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash --login
########## SBATCH Lines for Resource Request ##########
 
#SBATCH --time=00:10:00             # limit of wall clock time - how long the job will run (same as -t)
#SBATCH --nodes=1                   # the number of node requested.
#SBATCH --ntasks=1                  # the number of task to run
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=1           # the number of CPUs (or cores) per task (same as -c)
#SBATCH --mem-per-cpu=2G            # memory required per allocated CPU (or core) - amount of memory (in bytes)
#SBATCH --job-name test2            # you can give your job a name for easier identification (same as -J)
 
########## Command Lines to Run ##########
conda activate tf_gpu
python cifar100-vgg16.py
```

---

SLURM output file:

```
> /opt/software/Python/3.6.4-foss-2018a/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:523: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint8 = np.dtype([("qint8", np.int8, 1)])
/opt/software/Python/3.6.4-foss-2018a/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:524: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_quint8 = np.dtype([("quint8", np.uint8, 1)])
/opt/software/Python/3.6.4-foss-2018a/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:525: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint16 = np.dtype([("qint16", np.int16, 1)])
/opt/software/Python/3.6.4-foss-2018a/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:526: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_quint16 = np.dtype([("quint16", np.uint16, 1)])
/opt/software/Python/3.6.4-foss-2018a/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:527: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint32 = np.dtype([("qint32", np.int32, 1)])
/opt/software/Python/3.6.4-foss-2018a/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:532: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  np_resource = np.dtype([("resource", np.ubyte, 1)])
Tensorflow version 1.10.1
Keras version 2.1.6-tf
Scikit learn version 0.20.0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cifar100-vgg16.py", line 39, in <module>
    print("Number of GPUs Available:", len(tensorflow.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')))
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'config'
```

Comment: `/opt/software/Python` does not look like a `conda` env path. So I would guess that no conda env is activated. Try adding `source <path of ana/miniconda>/etc/profile.d/conda.sh` before the `activate` line

Comment: Thank you, @FlyingTeller.  How can I locate this conda.sh file?

Comment: You can find the path of your conda installation by running `echo $CONDA_PREFIX`

Comment: Thanks, @FlyingTeller.  I added the path "~/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" (which does exist).  However, that did not activate the tf_gpu conda environment.  I figured there may be a conda.sh file for the tf_gpu environment, so I searched for it in "~/anaconda3/envs/tf_gpu/etc"  However, that folder only has a "conda" directory with "activate.d" and "deactivate.d" subdirectories.

Comment: Just to clarify, I meant to have two lines: `source ~/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh` followed by `conda activate tf_gpu`

Comment: Does it work when you replace `python cifar100-vgg16.py` with `conda run -n tf_gpu python cifar100-vgg16.py`? Can you report theoutput of `which python` and `type python` put after the activate command?

Comment: @FlyingTeller.  Your solution of replacing python cifar100-vgg16.py with conda run -n tf_gpu python cifar100-vgg16.py worked.  Thank you so much!  The output of which python and type python are /opt/software/Python/3.6.4-foss-2018a/bin/python and
python is /opt/software/Python/3.6.4-foss-2018a/bin/python

Comment: The shebang with `bash -l`only works if you have run `conda init bash` for the user before (do not do this in the script). If you wanted further troubleshooting, include your `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile` (if they exist). But in general `conda run` is the preferred solution for programmatic execution of code within an environment.

Answer (score -3):

There is a mistake in your job script. Replace `conda activate tf_gpu` with `source activate tf_gpu`.

Also, I guess you need to load the module so that you can use it. It would be something like `module load anaconda` check `module avail` for the list of available modules.

But looks like you HPC doesn't need a module load as it identifies `conda` without `module load`.

EDIT: [FlytingTeller](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5012099/flyingteller) said that `source activate` is replaced with `conda activate` in 2017. I know this.

I don't know if this works on HPCs. To prove my point here is the output of Swansea SUNBIRD, when I use `conda activate`.

```bash
(base) hell@Dell-Precision-T7910:~$ ssh sunbird 
Last login: Wed Aug 10 15:30:29 2022 from en003013.swan.ac.uk

====================== Supercomputing Wales - Sunbird ========================

   This system is for authorised users, if you do not have authorised access
        please disconnect immediately, and contact Technical Support.

 -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

            For user guides, documentation and technical support:
                  Web: http://portal.supercomputing.wales

 -------------------------- Message of the Day -------------------------------

  SUNBIRD has returned to service unchanged.  Further information on 
    the maintenance outage and future work will be distributed soon.

===============================================================================
[s.1915438@sl2 ~]$ module load anaconda/3
[s.1915438@sl2 ~]$ conda activate base

CommandNotFoundError: Your shell has not been properly configured to use 'conda activate'.
If your shell is Bash or a Bourne variant, enable conda for the current user with

    $ echo ". /apps/languages/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" >> ~/.bashrc

or, for all users, enable conda with

    $ sudo ln -s /apps/languages/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh /etc/profile.d/conda.sh

The options above will permanently enable the 'conda' command, but they do NOT
put conda's base (root) environment on PATH.  To do so, run

    $ conda activate

in your terminal, or to put the base environment on PATH permanently, run

    $ echo "conda activate" >> ~/.bashrc

Previous to conda 4.4, the recommended way to activate conda was to modify PATH in
your ~/.bashrc file.  You should manually remove the line that looks like

    export PATH="/apps/languages/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"

^^^ The above line should NO LONGER be in your ~/.bashrc file! ^^^


[s.1915438@sl2 ~]$ source activate base
(base) [s.1915438@sl2 ~]$
```

Here is the output of Cardiff HAWK when I use `conda activate`.

```bash
(base) hell@Dell-Precision-T7910:~$ ssh cardiff 
Last login: Tue Aug  2 09:32:44 2022 from en003013.swan.ac.uk
======================== Supercomputing Wales - Hawk ==========================

   This system is for authorised users, if you do not have authorised access
       please disconnect immediately, and contact Technical Support.

 -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

            For user guides, documentation and technical support:
                   Web: http://portal.supercomputing.wales

 -------------------------- Message of the Day -------------------------------

 - WGP Gluster mounts are now RO on main login nodes.
 - WGP RW access is via Ser Cymru system or dedicated access VM.

===============================================================================

[s.1915438@cl1 ~]$ module load anaconda/
anaconda/2019.03  anaconda/2020.02  anaconda/3        
anaconda/2019.07  anaconda/2021.11  
[s.1915438@cl1 ~]$ module load anaconda/2021.11 
INFO: To setup environment run:
      eval "$(/apps/languages/anaconda/2021.11/bin/conda shell.bash hook)"
  or just:
      source activate
[s.1915438@cl1 ~]$ conda activate

CommandNotFoundError: Your shell has not been properly configured to use 'conda activate'.
To initialize your shell, run

    $ conda init <SHELL_NAME>

Currently supported shells are:
  - bash
  - fish
  - tcsh
  - xonsh
  - zsh
  - powershell

See 'conda init --help' for more information and options.

IMPORTANT: You may need to close and restart your shell after running 'conda init'.


[s.1915438@cl1 ~]$ conda activate base

CommandNotFoundError: Your shell has not been properly configured to use 'conda activate'.
To initialize your shell, run

    $ conda init <SHELL_NAME>

Currently supported shells are:
  - bash
  - fish
  - tcsh
  - xonsh
  - zsh
  - powershell

See 'conda init --help' for more information and options.

IMPORTANT: You may need to close and restart your shell after running 'conda init'.


[s.1915438@cl1 ~]$ source activate base
(2021.11)[s.1915438@cl1 ~]$
```

The conda versions are certainly after 2020 not 2017. SInce, the question was about a HPC cluster, that I why said replace `conda activate` with `source activate`, to activate the first conda environment.

Anyone with a possible explanation?

EDIT 2: I think I have an explanation.

```bash
[s.1915438@sl2 ~]$ cat ~/.bashrc
# .bashrc
# Dynamically generated by: genconfig  (Do not edit!)

# Source global definitions
if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
    . /etc/bashrc
fi

# Load saved modules
module load null

# Personal settings file
if [ -f $HOME/.myenv ]
then
    source $HOME/.myenv
fi
```

The `~/.bashrc` does not contain the path to `conda.sh`. I think this is true for many HPCs.

Comment: `source activate` has been replaced in 2017 with `conda activate`, see [here](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/release-notes.html#id266)

Comment: @FlyingTeller I don't this is true on HPCs, at least the one that I have used. I have added some proof in the answer. Please have a look at it. Maybe you can tell me my mistake.